# Extract info when JSON when key changes in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm quite new to Python so please excuse me if my terminology is not 100% accurate or if this is quite simple

I currently have the code:

```
    import requests
    POINTS = requests.get('https://api.torn.com/market/?selections=pointsmarket&key=jtauOcpEwz0W0V5M').json()
    POINTSA = POINTS['pointsmarket']
    print (POINTSA)
```

I want to print the cost of the very first key. However, the number for the first key will always change.

At the time of posting the first key is 9765126 as seen here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqkZR.jpg

So the line would be (I think):

```
     POINTSA = POINTS['pointsmarket'][9765126]['cost']
```

However in 5 minutes time, the 9765126 key will change to something else. How do I get it to print the 1st cost entry regardless of the first key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can try the following sample of getting the keys as a list then getting the first index

```py
keys = list(POINTS['pointsmarket'].keys()) # Get all keys and convert to a list
POINTS['pointsmarket'][keys[0]]['cost']
```